# Python Type Hint Instances of class

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm unsure of the Python convention for type hinting for this situation

I have a class

```py
class A(object):
     pass
```

And a not defined number of subclasses of `A`, i.e.:

```py
class B(A):
     pass

class C(A):
     pass

class D(A):
     pass
.....
```

If I want that a function, accepts **only instances** of `B,C,D`, and **not instances** of `A`, what is the correct typing notation?

```py
def fnc(x: # Only instances of B,C,D,...):
   pass
```

With the notation

```py
def fnc(x: A):
   pass
```

the function will accept also instances of `A` itself, correct?

Comment: Please note: Unlike languages like C, Python type hinting does not preclude use of a different object type from that suggested by the type hint. Therefore, there is no way type hinting can prevent a class from accepting 'accepts only instances of B,C,D, and not instances of A'

Comment: Not the cleanest, but `Union[B, C, D]` should work.

Comment: You'd have to be explicit. There's nothing special about `B`, `C`, and `D` compared to other potential subclasses of `A`.

Comment: If you can think of something that makes them unique, you can define an intermediate subclass of `A` (call it `E`), then use `E` as the parent of `B` et al. and define `def fnc(x: E): ...`

Comment: (By "unique", I mean what makes an instance of `B` et al. suitable as argument for `fnc` where a "plain" instance of `A` is not?)

Comment: I'm going to immediately regret asking this: But how did you end up a situation with a concrete superclass that has subclasses, all of which are compatible with this function but for which the superclass is *not*? My professional recommendation is to pour copious amounts of gasoline on this design choice and then set it ablaze.

Comment: Read about abstract base classes, perhaps? If `A` is abstract and has at least one abstract method, then no `A` instance can exist. Otherwise you 100% do not need it, it is against the core of types theory. Set of "all possible `A` subclasses" is not distinguishable from "`A` and every `A` subclass", obviously (why `class NewA(A): pass` is allowed and `A` itself - not?).

Comment: I found this situation in TensorFlow. I have a custom Model and I want to hint that a specific arg can be one layer, for example, `tf.keras.layers.Dense`, `tf.keras.layers.Conv2d`, etc,..; these specific layers are my `B`, `C`, `D` classes mentioned above. All these ones inherit from `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, which is a generic class, that cannot be use directly.

Answer (score 1):

Python hinting is just that (a hint that is a suggestion and therefore not enforceable).

You can hint which types a variable or argument should be, but cannot preclude a type.

So in the given example in the question, you can hint for `B`, `C`, and `D` as the arguments and just elect to omit `A` as an argument.

So it looks like this:

```py
class A(object):
     pass


class B(A):
     pass

class C(A):
     pass

class D(A):
     pass


def fnc(x:B, y:C, z:D):
    pass
```

One option is to use notation like a preceding underscore like this `_A` or `__A` to indicate the difference between a conceptually "private" and "public" class.

Also, it might be something specifically mentioned in the function docstring if it is of importance.